# Simple text classification with Naive Bayes in Python - KeyError

Tags: python, csv, sklearn-pandas, naivebayes

I am trying to train a model using a csv file that has text and categories. The model is working correctly but I am getting a keyerror. I suspect it is something to do with how the csv is being read.

The csv file looks like this:

| text | category |
| --- | --- |
| hello | greeting |
| who are you? | question |

The code I have is:

```
train = pd.read_csv(filepath)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
model.fit(train.text,train.category)

def predict_category(s, train=train, model=model):
pred = model.predict([s])
return train.category[pred[0]]
```

All of this executes fine until I try to input a string into the predict_category function, e.g.

```
predict_category('Hi')
```

Results in KeyError: 'Greeting'

So it seems the model is working but the KeyError isn't printing the result.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: From what you've shown, it looks like `model.predict()` is already returning `greeting`, and you don't need to look it up a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have train as input parameter in your function, model.predict gives you already the result of your prediction. You were trying to get the value of train.category['greetings'] and that was causing the KeyError since train.category does not have 'greetings' in index.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

train = pd.read_csv(filepath)
model_nb = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
model_nb.fit(train['text'], train['category'])


def predict_category(s, model=model_nb):
    pred = model.predict([s])
    return pred[0]


predict_category(s='Hi')
```